# SCRIPT ERROR 70 when checking if a multiple select index is selected IE11

Tags: javascript, select, internet-explorer-11, permission-denied

w/I have a multiple select that lists counties of a state:

```
<select name="SAcounty" id="SAcounty" size="7" class="" multiple  onchange="getcities();" tabindex="47" style="font-size: 10px; color: black">
                        </select>
```

The event function getcities works perfectly the first time you select a county.  but when you change to another county i get the permission denied error.

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById('SAcounty').length; i++) {

        if (document.getElementById('SAcounty').options[i].selected) {
            k = k + 1;
        }
    }
```

The error is occuring on the line for

```
    if (document.getElementById('SAcounty').options[i].selected)
```

This worked perfectly before we moved to IE 11 without comp mode but now nothing i change is getting around this error.

It seems that the problem doesnt occur until ".selected" is called.  I can set a variable to document.getElementById('SAcounty').options[i] no problem but as soon as .selected is added.... error.

The page is contained in a frame but all the functionality is contained within the same frame and no interaction occurs with any others.

Any help?

Comment: Messing around with document modes... the wanted functionality works with document mode 8.  However we are trying to making everything work with edge.

Answer (score 0):

I've created this Stack Snippet showing what I see when I do this.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('SAcounty');
el.options[5].selected = true;
for (var i = 0; i < el.options.length; i++) {
  var option = el.options[i];
  if (option.selected) {
    alert(option.text);
  }
}
```

```html
<select multiple id="SAcounty">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option selected>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
</select>
```

This alerts "3", then "6" in IE11, on Edge. If you see something different, please let me know...